# How do I grab the variable NAME and not the VALUE of the variable in ColdFusion?

Tags: variables, coldfusion

The basic idea is this: I have a form that generates form fields dynamically so let's say there are 5 evens people can sign up for (they all cost $10) then those 5 evens will be displayed. Like this:

```
          <tr>
            <th><label>#SeminarWisTitle#</label></th>
            <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="#SeminarWisID#" value="10.00" onclick="CheckChoice(this);" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();" class="checkbox" /> Individual Webinar ($119)</label>
            </tr>
          </cfoutput>
```

Now because of the Javascript the value on all these events will be 10.00 but the NAME of the form field will be unique, and that is what I actaully want to store in the database.

This is the code I've written:

```
<cfparam name="seminarBulkSignUp_List" default="">
            <cfoutput query="qSeminarWisTwo">
                <cfparam name="FORM.#SeminarWisID#" default="">

                <cfif #FORM[#SeminarWisID#]# neq "">
                    <cfset seminarBulkSignUp_List = ListAppend(seminarBulkSignUp_List, #FORM[#SeminarWisID#]#)>
                </cfif>
            </cfoutput>

            <cfset FORM.SeminarWisTitle = #seminarBulkSignUp_List#>
```

So with this code, I run a query for ALL the possible events, and then just check against the form that has been submitted to see which ones are "blank" as in not selected, and the ones that are selected i want to add to a list to store in the database.

Now this works as far as letting me know which events were selected and which not, but i want the list to compile the actual FORM FIELD names not the value they have. How would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfloop list="#StructKeyList(FORM)#" index="thisField">
    My field name: #thisField#<br/>
    My field value: #FORM[thisField]#<br/>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Apply as necessary.

Comment: Aghh I'm stupid I also could have just removed the #FORM[ from inside the ListAppend and I'd get exactly what I needed! So this line needs to be like this :                    <cfset seminarBulkSignUp_List = ListAppend(seminarBulkSignUp_List, #SeminarWisID#)>

Comment: You've got a missing </cfoutput>. And it's a good idea to put your <cfoutput> outside of your <cfloop>.

Comment: Thanks Evik, I actually have the output in my code it just didn't copy over here for some reason. It works now though as I mentioned above the answer was right in front of me and I didn't see it.

Comment: @Evik, fixed, good catch. I'm not a fan of wrapping <cfoutput> around things that don't need to be evaluated.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes, the extra code (to me) is an eyesore. Personally, I proceed with "my server works for me, I don't work for the server".  The time saved or spent doesn't matter, but it's a lot easier to make simple mistakes (like forgetting to close an output) when you try to save the server a little work.

Comment: @Evik Concur. Readability first. Code adjusted.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes, I am just catching up on your blog.  You've got great examples, such as: "It is true, IsDefined() is extraordinarily convenient, because it relieves the developer of any accountability on logical flow through their application. By using it, you are stating that you think you have a pretty good idea of how your application is supposed to work, but in some rare instances that elude you, there seems to be a point where your variables don't exist. So, rather than digging deeper, gaining insight into the real issue, you band-aid to the problem--while a far greater one persists."

Comment: Note that one can use FORM.fieldList instead of StructKeyList(form)

Comment: You also might want to skip `form.fieldlist` as it was not a part of the original form